# Scala: Read file with a custom delimiter

Tags: scala

Reading files line by line is simple:

```
scala.io.Source.fromFile(file).getLines()
```

but how can I iterate over a file using a different delimiter than new-lines?

I could load the entire file as a string and then split that, but I expect that to perform poorly on large files (`readDelimited1`). Alternatively I could resolve to wrapping Java's scanner, which will probably perform better, but it is a bit ugly (`readDelimited2`).

```
def readDelimited1(file: java.io.File, delimiter : String) : Iterator[String] = {
  scala.io.Source.fromFile(file).getLines().mkString("\n").split(delimiter).iterator
}

def readDelimited2(file: java.io.File, delimiter : String) : Iterator[String] = {
  val scanner = new java.util.Scanner(file).useDelimiter(delimiter)
  collection.JavaConversions.asScalaIterator(scanner)
}
```

Is there a nice Scala'isque way of iterating over a file using a custom delimiter?

Comment: i don't think playing with Scanner is a bad idea.

Comment: After importing `JavaConversions._`, you can just write `....useDelimiter(delimiter).asScala`, which you may prefer.

Answer (score 1):

`scala.io.Source.fromFile(file).getLines()` calls `String java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(boolean ignoreLF) throws IOException`

It's not easy to change it.Using `Scanner` is a good way.